# How to add new file extension to be recognized as html in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have file.myext in my project.  The contents of this file is simple HTML but Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize the file as an HTML file.

How can I setup Visual Studio Code to see this `.myext` file as an "alias" file extension to HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Files: Associations` setting you can use to set this:

```json
"files.associations": {
  "*.myText": "html"
}
```

[image: vs code files: association setting]

After setting this, Visual Studio Code will recognize any `.myText` file as an HTML file:

[image: example .myText file showing as HTML]

Comment: I misread `.myExt` in your question as `.myText` but the solution is still the same.